# How do I insert hidden field (Javascript) into XML via JSP codes?

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, hidden

I am trying to insert data from the Javascript hidden fields into an XML but however, only 'null' come out. I have declared the variables but it seems that it cannot capture the hidden field. I am at my wits end and I hope that my problem can be solved.

```
**<<-----I use session to pass the value to the XML page----->>**


<%
String X = (String)session.getAttribute("X");
    String Y = (String)session.getAttribute("Y");
    String W = (String)session.getAttribute("W");
    String H = (String)session.getAttribute("H");       
session.setAttribute("X",X);
session.setAttribute("Y",Y);
session.setAttribute("W",W);
session.setAttribute("H",H);
%>



**<<------Snippet of Javascript codes------->>**

function moveIt(){ 

if (!moveEnabled||!MovableItem) return;

// display info during testing

X = MovableItem.offsetLeft;

Y = MovableItem.offsetTop;

W = MovableItem.offsetWidth;

H = MovableItem.offsetHeight;

 ==Some codes here==

  document.getElementById('X').value = X;     
  document.getElementById('Y').value = Y;
  document.getElementById('W').value = W;
  document.getElementById('H').value = H;
```

}

```
**<<-----JSP codes that I need to pass the values onto an XML----->>**

 <form name='form1' action='UpdateXML.jsp' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name=source value="<%=src%>" />
<input type='hidden' id="X" name="X" value="<%=X%>"/>
<input type='hidden' id="Y" name="Y" value="<%=Y%>"/>
<input type='hidden' id="W" name="W" value="<%=W%>"/>
<input type='hidden' id="H" name="H" value="<%=H%>"/> 

<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='editcompany.jsp'">Back!</button>
<button type="submit">Insert Into XML!</button>
</form>
```

*I need to insert the hidden field(data) into an XML. I tried but it comes out as 'null'. Is there anyone that can help me solve this problem? Thanks a bunch!*

Answer (score 0):

Is the first file UpdateXML.jsp? If so, shouldn't there be request.getParameter()?

And it seems 4 lines of session.setAttribute() below do nothing useful:

```
<%
String X = (String)session.getAttribute("X");
String Y = (String)session.getAttribute("Y");
String W = (String)session.getAttribute("W");
String H = (String)session.getAttribute("H");       
session.setAttribute("X",X);
session.setAttribute("Y",Y);
session.setAttribute("W",W);
session.setAttribute("H",H);
%>
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I have actually solved the problem. Now I face another problem of inserting multiple records into the XML file. Any ideas?